# Unit Tests on Single DB

Tags: developer, phpunit

My rig has a CMS & Civi combined database. This was to make life easier through drush sql-sync from @prod to @dev.

However, @dev is a vagrant box, with two databases, one for CMS, one for Civi.

When I run unit tests, instead of it cloning from the CMS database it clones from the old civi one.

My question is, how can I get it to clone from the CMS database? I've changed settings in the local test file and the civicrm.settings.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the new, fledgling, e2e tests are my answer...